# How to read all lines in a file from a URI?

Tags: c#, uri

I'm currently reading the content of a `.srt` like this:

```
var assetURL = "some url";
var textFromFile = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(assetURL);
```

However, I need to be able to loop through all lines, like this:

```
 string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"subs.srt");
 foreach (string line in text)
 {
    // Do something
 }
```

I can't do it like that because `File.ReadAllLines` does not support URIs. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you split the `textFromFile` at the newline character?

Comment: @Steve +1 , i was about to suggest the same

Comment: @Steve splitting by new line character can be dangerous. You must remember that there could be two cases: `\n` and `\r\n` (depending on a system). So it is better to use `StringReader` that do it for us.

Comment: Well, if this is the case then Split could also use an array of splitting chars. But nevertheless you have a valid point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always split a string by [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] lines = textFromFile.Split(new []{ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: What if content comes from system, where new line character differs from `Environment.NewLine`. F.e. unix?

Comment: @pwas: you can split by `"\n"` if you want.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, and I think it is worth to mention it in a answer :)

Comment: @pwas: i just didnt want to confuse OP. Using `\n` could also be wrong since `\r` remains as a portion of the split string if it's a non-unix system like windows. Maybe the comments are helpful.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see, that is why I preffer `StringReader` solution - it handles both cases correctly. Especially, we don't know the source of file and if it is was written in unix or non-unix system.

Comment: @pwas: yes, `StringReader` seems to be a good approach for this case. I think you can also use `textFromFile.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. However, that removes also empty lines which might not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringReader`:

```
using (var sr = new StringReader(textFromFile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       // sth with a line
    }
}
```

Why it could be better than splitting by `Environment.NewLine`? It will handle both cases - when the new line character is `\r\n` or `\n`.